# How the .class file from java can be ran in almost all environments

Tags: java

This question is always there for me.What gives the power to these .class files to be ran everywhere.I technically know that it is portability.But would like to hear in layman's terms and interesting examples

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A three letter answer: **JVM**

Comment: See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode

Comment: See [About the Java Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain this in as simple terms as possible.

You write your Java code and save it in a `.java` file. The `.java` file is then turned into a `.class` file by the Java compiler.

Now what does this `.class` file contain? Does it contain machine code that a processor can directly run? No. If it really did Java wouldn't have been cross-platform. `.class` files contain Java *bytecode*.

No processor can directly run Java bytecode. People have to install something called a "Java Runtime Environment" (JRE). The JRE can read bytecode! The JRE interprets the bytecode in the `.class` file and turns them into processor instructions.

Since there are different processor architectures (different kinds of processors) and different OSs, there needs to be different JREs. There is one JRE for Windows 32 bit, one for Windows 64 bit, one for Mac etc.

Here's an analogy:

You wrote something in English and you want a Japanese speaker, a Chinese Speaker, and a Korean speaker to understand what you wrote. How do you do this. You hire a translator for Japanese, Chinese and Korean respectively! So that the same English text can be understood by all 3 people!

Answer (score 0):

Java source code is compiled to bytecodes, which is what is stored in the .class files that are generated by the compiler.  These bytecodes are executed by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).  The clue here is in the name, 'Virtual'.  The JVM takes each bytecode and interprets it, meaning it converts it from the virtual machine representation to that of the physical machine on which the JVM is running.  That way, once the JVM has been ported to a new hardware/OS combination all Java code will work on that platform, unchanged.

Often this is a one-to-one mapping (for things like logical binary operations).  However, this can be far more complex and, to get good performance, require analysis of potentially long sequences of bytecodes.  This is where adaptive compilation comes in.  This uses Just-In-Time (JIT) compilation to compile the HotSpots of your code when the application is running. When you start executing a loop the JVM will notice repeated calls to the same method and compile and cache that method so it does not need to be interpreted each time.

JIT compilation can often provide better performance than more traditional Ahead of Time (AOT) compilation, especially in a language like Java where classes can be loaded dynamically at runtime.  Speculative optimisations and more aggressive method inlining are all possible with a JIT and not AOT.

OpenJDK provides two JIT compilers: C1 and C2 (sometimes referred to as client and server).  These provide different profiles to their compilation.  C1 warms up faster but provides a lower optimal level of performance.  C1 warms up more slowly but optimises better.  More recently tiered compilation is used, which starts with C1 and then switches to C2.

Azul (who I work for) just launched our replacement for the C2 JIT called Falcon.  This is based on the LLVM open source project and is designed to optimise better for modern hardware.